# Checkbox enable readonly Input Not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Can anybody see why this is not working? It does not make the input field read only when the checkbox is not checked.

I have followed all the online advice so far and read much advice but even though I have followed what I could it does not work, however it throws no errors.

Would be great-full if anybody can see why.

```html
<div class='div1'>

  <input type="checkbox" class='Xcheckbox' id="byname" name="searchforname" title='Search For All Listings With Sellers Name' value="sellersname" onclick="chbxX(this); <?php $extrasearch==='sellersname'; ?>" <?php if ($extrasearch==='sellersname' ): ?>  checked="checked"
  <?php endif; ?> >

  <label for="byname" class='nameheader' title='Search Date Range'>
    <b>Seller's Name</b>
  </label>

  <input type="text" id='sellersname' name="SellersName" placeholder="Sellers Name" class="sellersname" title='Type The Sellers Name' value="<?php echo $sellersname ?>">

</div>


<script>
  $(function() {

    if ($("#byname").prop('checked') == false) {
      document.getElementById("sellersname").setAttribute("readonly", true);
    } else {
      document.getElementById("sellersname").removeAttribute("readonly");
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I think it's the disabled attribute you want to toggle.

Comment: yes, but iv tried also with readonly='true' added to the input field  and they remain read only when checked...Oh i see what your saying, i shal try. thanks

Comment: it looks like the code is being run when the page is loading. You probably should have this code run when a 'click' event is detected on one of the checkboxes.

Comment: ok il try as you say. thanks#

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with readonly, disabled should do what you want.

Comment: ok il try the disabled

Comment: try: `document.getElementById("sellersname").readOnly = true;` or `$("#sellersname").prop('readonly', true);`. And make sure  your if condition is working properly.

Comment: Setting an input to read-only the field cannot be modified. However, it will allow the user to tab to it, highlight it, and copy the text from it. When it's disabled, the prior behaviour is disabled. You can read more about both properties in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="position:relative; width:fit-content; height:fit-content; float:left; clear:both; margin-top:30px;">

<input type="checkbox" class='Xcheckbox' id="byname" name="searchforname" title='Search For All Listings With Sellers Name'  value="sellersname" onclick="chbxX(this); <?php $extrasearch==='sellersname'; ?>" <?php if ($extrasearch==='sellersname'):  ?> checked="checked" <?php endif; ?> ></input>

<label for="byname" class='nameheader' title='Search Date Range' ><b>Seller's Name</b></label>

<input type="text" id='byname2' name="SellersName" placeholder="Sellers Name" class="sellersname" title='Type The Sellers Name' disabled='true' value="<?php echo $sellersname ?>"  ></input>

</div>



function chbxX(objX)
{


var that = objX;

(objX);

if(document.getElementById(that.id).checked === true) {

document.getElementById('byname').checked = false;
document.getElementById('bynumber').checked = false;
document.getElementById('bylistingid').checked = false;


document.getElementById('byname2').disabled = true;
document.getElementById('bynumber2').disabled = true;
document.getElementById('bylistingid2').disabled = true;



}
document.getElementById(that.id).checked = true;
document.getElementById(that.id+"2").disabled = false;
}
```

THANKS FOR YOUR HELP FOLKS. It really helped.

Comment: Im now stuck on how to add a Click event on the INPUT to mark it checked And operational for input again. Any Ideas Any1 , Or should i make another thread>

Comment: you can add another button to enable it, if is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to inverse your condition:

```js
$(function() {
  /* event handler added just for debugging purpose  */
  $('#byname').on('change', function(e) {
    $('#sellersname').prop('readonly', !$("#byname").prop('checked'));
  });
});
```

```css
#sellersname[readonly]{
  background-color:#ccc;
  border-width:1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='div1'>
  <input type="checkbox" class='Xcheckbox' id="byname" name="searchforname" title='Search For All Listings With Sellers Name' value="sellersname" />
  <label for="byname" class='nameheader' title='Search Date Range'><b>Seller's Name</b></label>
  <input type="text" id='sellersname' name="SellersName" placeholder="Sellers Name" class="sellersname" title='Type The Sellers Name' />

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do this. I did remove the php code else the below code example would not be able to run properly.

When using this, make sure you set the initial value on the input. So if your checkbox will be unchecked on page load, make sure the input as a readonly attribute set.

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
    if ($("#byname").prop('checked') == false) {
      $("#sellersname").prop('readOnly', true);
    } else {
      $("#sellersname").prop('readOnly', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
input:-moz-read-only {
  /* For Firefox */
  background-color: #ccc;
}

input:read-only {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='div1'>

  <input type="checkbox" class='Xcheckbox' id="byname" name="searchforname" title='Search For All Listings With Sellers Name' value="sellersname">

  <label for="byname" class='nameheader' title='Search Date Range'>
    <b>Seller's Name</b>
  </label>

  <input type="text" id='sellersname' readonly name="SellersName" placeholder="Sellers Name" class="sellersname" title='Type The Sellers Name' value="Donna">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure jQuery. You can try to run this code and see if it helps:

```js
function clickFunction(){
    
    $("input").on("click", function () {

        if ($("#byname").prop("checked") == false){
            $("#sellersname").attr("readonly", true);
        }

        else {
            $("#sellersname").removeAttr("readonly");
        }
    });
    
}


$(function (){
    clickFunction();        
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="div1">

<input type="checkbox" class="Xcheckbox" id="byname" name="searchforname" title="Search For All Listings With Sellers Name"  value="sellersname"></input>

<label for="byname" class="nameheader" title="Search Date Range" ><b>Seller's Name</b></label>

<input type="text" id="sellersname" name="SellersName" placeholder="Sellers Name" class="sellersname" title="Type The Sellers Name"></input>

</div>
```